# Meus resultados não corresponderam com o esperado da Lei de Benford. Há algo de errado?

Tags: c#

Olá, sou um programador iniciante e resolvi escrever um "rascunho de guardanapo" para testar a Lei de Benford (Benford's Law). Apesar de o código não estar com uma boa qualidade e mal optimizado, acredito que a parte matemática está correta.

As variáveis aleatórias foram calculadas num intervalo entre 0 e 1500, atendendo, portanto aos critérios da lei, e o grupo amostral foi de 10000000. Porém, apesar disso, os valores não se aproximam tanto da curva esperada, principalmente do terceiro em diante.

```
using System;

namespace Teste_para_sempre
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero0 = 0;
            int numero1s = 0;
            int numero2s = 0;
            int numero3s = 0;
            int numero4s = 0;
            int numero5s = 0;
            int numero6s = 0;
            int numero7s = 0;
            int numero8s = 0;
            int numero9s = 0;
            int[] numero = new int[10000000];
            var teste = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                numero[i] = teste.Next(0, 1500);

                for(int a=1; a<= 10000000; a++)
                {
                    if (numero[i] == 0)
                    {
                        numero0++;
                        a = 10000000;
                    }
                    if(numero[i]/a == 1)
                    {
                        numero1s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 2)
                    {
                        numero2s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 3)
                    {
                        numero3s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 4)
                    {
                        numero4s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 5)
                    {
                        numero5s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 6)
                    {
                        numero6s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 7)
                    {
                        numero7s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 8)
                    {
                        numero8s++;
                    }
                    if (numero[i] / a == 9)
                    {
                        numero9s++;
                    }
                    a = (a * 10) - 1;
                }


            }
            int total = numero0 + numero1s + numero2s + numero3s + numero4s + numero5s + numero6s + numero7s + numero8s + numero9s;
            Console.WriteLine("Numeros que começam com 1: {0}\nNumeros que começam com 2: {1}\nNumeros que começam com 3: {2}\nNumeros que começam com 4: {3}\nNumeros que começam com 5: {4}\nNumeros que começam com 6: {5}\nNumeros que começam com 7: {6}\nNumeros que começam com 8: {7}\nNumeros que começam com 9: {8}\n", numero1s, numero2s, numero3s, numero4s, numero5s, numero6s, numero7s, numero8s, numero9s);
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui está um vídeo falando sobre a Benford's Law e o seu papel em detecção de fraudes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etx0k1nLn78

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217869

Comment: Newcomb-Benford se mostra útil justo em achar valores gerados de forma aleatória , talvez a sua geração esteja com um viés , tente baixar alguma série real do Internet (IBGE etc) e tentar aplicar.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas. Acho que o meu intervalo de distribuição está muito pequeno para observar essas diferenças usando a função de aleatoriedade. Talvez utilizar de um banco de dados real ou ajustar o intervalo de distribuição para uma escala logarítmica possa dar certo.

Comment: Quando li sobre NB na primeira vez fiz um teste com uma base na empresa em que trabalho , o resultado foi consistente com a teoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava sendo que, para que a Lei de Benford funcione, os intervalos superiores e inferiores da variável mudam de indivíduo para indivíduo. Por exemplo: Ao ser aplicado uma prova para uma turma de "n" alunos, não se pode considerar que todos os alunos tem a mesma probabilidade de tirar uma mesma nota, pois trata-se de um grupo heterogêneo. Assim, considerando o intervalo de notas possíveis para cada aluno, diferente, podemos observar a Lei de Benford funcionando apropriadamente.

Dessa vez, fui menos desleixado na escrita do código:

```
using System;

namespace Teste_para_sempre
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int population = 10000000;
            int pontuaçãoMinima_LimiteInferior = 0;
            int pontuaçãoMinima_LimiteSuperior = 100;
            int pontuaçãoMaxima_LimiteInferior = 1000;
            int pontuaçãoMaxima_LimiteSuperior = 10000;
            int[] termoInicial = new int[10];

            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < population; i++)
            {
                int pontuaçãoMinima = rand.Next(pontuaçãoMinima_LimiteInferior, pontuaçãoMinima_LimiteSuperior);
                int pontuaçãoMaxima = rand.Next(pontuaçãoMaxima_LimiteInferior, pontuaçãoMaxima_LimiteSuperior);

                int random = rand.Next(pontuaçãoMinima, pontuaçãoMaxima);

                while (random >= 10)
                {
                    random /= 10;
                }

                termoInicial[random]++; 
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Termo {0}: {1}",i, termoInicial[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```